# Irreducible subcontinuum of Lorenz attractor?

Tags: gn.general-topology, ds.dynamical-systems

In my first question [Lorenz attractor path-connected?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/321261/lorenz-attractor-path-connected), some are saying the Lorenz attractor $\mathscr L$ is not path-connected.

But suppose $x$ and $y$ are two points in different path components of the attractor.  By Zorn's Lemma there is a subcontinuum of $\mathscr L$ which is irreducible between $x$ and $y$ (no proper subcontinuum of it contains these two points).  I am having hard time imagining any irreducible subcontinua in $\mathscr L$ other than paths...

Are the "butterfly's wings" connected, individually?

EDIT:  It seems a lot of people are not understanding my question.  I want you to demonstrate an irreducible subcontinuum of $\mathscr L$ which is not an arc.  If it is not path-connected, then there must be such an example.  And the example cannot be $\mathscr L$ itself, because $\mathscr L$ is the union of two proper subcontinua, and these sub continua extend to points in their complements by small connecting arcs.

Comment: Look at this image https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:ContinuBJK.svg

Comment: @AntonPetrunin so could the butterfly wings be of that type?

Comment: The principle is the same.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin right, it seems possible, but it's not obvious.  The wing could be Cantor set times circle, for instance, which is not connected.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin but what are you applying this principle towards?  It does NOT apply, for instance, to the entire $\mathscr L$, because $\mathscr L$ is not indecomposable like the BJK continuum.  You can perhaps apply the principle to each wing... but I'd need supporting arguments.  It is not enough to just say "it's like the BJK continuum".

Comment: source: https://books.google.com/books?id=bVcZGMOA4AEC&pg=PA119&lpg=PA119&dq=lorenz+indecomposable&source=bl&ots=Brl4b5QGV9&sig=ACfU3U0Met9d6P9guphN_S0y9upL31_sdw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiv3YvftoLgAhVMS60KHbu7DZoQ6AEwBXoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=lorenz%20indecomposable&f=false

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of an irreducible continuum between two points that is not a path:

https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Irreducible_continuum

The situation with the Lorenz attractor is similar:  the orbit $E$ connected, in fact path connected, but not closed. The closure of a connected space is connected. However, you cannot connect points in $cl(E)\setminus E$ to $E$ by a curve.

Comment: but does Lorenz contain a sin(1/x) continuum?

Comment: @DouglasSirk No, it does not, but my answer to your statement: **I am having hard time imagining any irreducible subcontinua in L other than paths...**

Comment: but what irreducible continuum does it contain which is not an arc?  that is my question

Comment: @DouglasSirk I do not understand the question.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz The question is for an irreducible subcontinuum of the Lorenz attractor which is not an arc.

Comment: if you say that $\mathscr L$ is not path-connected, then there must be an irreducible subcontinuum containing two points in different path components, which is not itself a path. So my question is to specify such a continuum in $\mathscr L$.

Comment: @DouglasSirk Reffering to your previous post: **I do not mean only the line weaving around, but rather its closure.** The `weaving line' $L$ is connected, in fact path connected, but not closed. The closure of a connected space is connected. However, you cannot connect points in $cl{L}\setminus L$ to $L$ by a curve. This is a very similar situation to that described in the link provided in my answer.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz yes $\mathscr L$ is the compact closure of that orbit.  But I do not believe $\mathscr L$ itself is irreducible.

Comment: @Wojowu I modified my answer.

Comment: I understand your claim about the path-components.  However, $\mathscr L$ is not irreducible. A disc in the middle of a butterfly wing can probably be deleted so that what remains is connected.  This is why I think each of the two butterfly wings may be an irreducible subcontinuum, but that's only an idea.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz consider the sin(1/x) continuum.  you cannot connect a point  $p$ in the middle of the curve to a point  $q$ in the arc at the end with a path.  BUT you can connect it with a proper subcontinuum of the entire continuum.  So although the continuum is "path-irreducible" between $p$ and $q$, it is not  irreducible between $p$ and $q$.

Comment: the problem remains that path-irreducible does not imply irreducible. For another example illustrating this, think of the union of two BJK continua that intersect at one point. it is reducible between some points in different path components.